# How to create sub organization unit under aws organization unit using python and yaml file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

**Task: suborganization unit creation under aws organization unit(OU) using python and yaml**

using below code I am able to create multiple OU in aws organization

***yaml file:***

```
 accounts:
  - Organization-Unit: 
     test1
  - Organization-Unit: 
     test2
```

***Python file for creation of OU:***

```
     #!/usr/bin/env python
     from __future__ import print_function
     import json
     import boto3
     import yaml
     client = boto3.client('organizations')
     with open("xyz.yaml", 'r') as ymlfile:
       config = yaml.safe_load(ymlfile)
     accounts = config['accounts']

     for account in accounts:
       try:
         response = client.create_organizational_unit(
         ParentId = "",
         Name     = account['Organization-Unit'])
         print(response)         
       except Exception as error:
        print(error)
```

---

Now I want to create sub-OU under OU like below:

yaml file:

```
         accounts:
         - Organization-Unit: 
           test1
             - sub-Organization-Unit: 
                test3
        - Organization-Unit: 
           test2
```

How can I give reference of main OU to sub-OU?